# Android app widget preferences

Tags: android, android-appwidget, appwidgetprovider, android-appwidget-list

I am building an android app that has a list of objects, and every object has a field `category` which can be one of three possible categories.

There is an app widget that is 3x3 in size and has a list of mentioned objects in it. Now, I need to filter the list every time app widget is created. User goes to the widget page from the home screen, selects my list widget and when he/she drags it to the home screen, there should pop `WidgetSettingsActivity` that offers the user to filter the list with one of the three categories.

I am starting the activity from widget class with

```
        Intent i = new Intent(context, WidgetSettingsActivity.class);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
```

But when and where should I call it to get the dialog for every widget when the user sets it on the home screen?

Comment: I'm not really clear on what you're asking, but are you maybe looking for a [Configuration `Activity`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/#Configuring)? It'll be stated automatically when the user places a Widget.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for :) Can you convert it to answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Actually, it's been answered here before, so I'll just mark this as a duplicate. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad I could help. Cheers!